# Is this congestion control method for UDP feasible / sound?

Tags: networking, congestion-control

- Sender sends the data.
- Receiver waits a couple of seconds and then calculates the throughput rate / s
- Receiver sends the rate at which its receiving packets (bytes / s) to sender
- Sender calculates its rate of sending packets
- If the rate of sender is significantly higher, reduce it to match receiving rate.

Alternatively, a more advanced approach:

- Sender starts sending at a predefined min rate (eg. 1kb / s)
- Receiver sends the calculated receiving rate back to sender.
- If the receiving rate is the same as sending rate (taking latency into account) increase the rate by a set pct (eg. rate * 2)
- Keep doing this until the sending rate becomes higher than receiving rate.
- Keep monitoring the rates to account for changes in bandwidth increase / reduce rate if needed.

Could this work if you were to implement your own UDP congestion control algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is feasible.
Now, would this give you the expected result, or is it sound...

I think you're trying to address a problem that has been studied and standardized by the very smart peoples of IETF. I'd advise you to take a look at RTP/RTCP which sit on top of UDP, would it be only to understand why it's a tough problem and grab some ideas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_Control_Protocol

"The primary function of RTCP is to provide feedback on the quality of service (QoS) in media distribution by periodically sending statistics information to participants in a streaming multimedia session."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

The fact that it's main use case is audio/video streaming is, I think, not so important: the point of RTCP is to provide feedback among particpants about a UDP stream of data[*].

Be warned that:

- These are complicated protocols, because the problem at hand is indeed complicated.
- IIRC, RTCP does not define *what* the sender side should do with these QoS reports. It just formalize the way these reports are exchanged from side to side.

[*]: Well, not enterily true since in A/V, synchronization is an important aspect ("send/receive in a timely manner"), whereas what you're trying to do is "go as fast as possible, yet not too fast".